# 2.5.2 - Performance - Software Requirements and Fir.im

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect, appstore-approval

Apple Review Team reject my iOS App because of:

> Guideline 2.5.2 - Performance - Software Requirements
>
> During review, your app installed or launched executable code, which
>   is not permitted on the App Store. Specifically, your app uses the
>   itms-services URL scheme to install an app.
>
> Guideline 4.0 - Design
>
> Your app includes an update button or alerts the user to update the
>   app, but the update button or alert does not link directly to the
>   app’s page on the App Store.

I don't use itms-services and I checked that they do not even do the libraries I include.
This is my podfile:

```
  pod 'Bolts'
  pod 'FBSDKCoreKit'
  pod 'FBSDKLoginKit'
  pod 'FBSDKShareKit'
  pod 'Firebase/Core'
  pod 'Firebase/Database'
  pod 'Firebase/Auth'
  pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
  pod 'Fabric'
  pod 'Crashlytics'
  pod 'PageMenu'
```

after several questions to the resolution center, apple advised me to remove any reference to FIR.IM but I never included this library and there is no track in the code...

Answer (score 1):

Searching for `itms-services://` of whole workspace.

Comment: there is no reference within the whole project